# How can I bind two distinct actions to Ctrl-Shift-Key and Ctrl-Key in vi

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

I am trying to map two different actions to e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>:

```
map <C-S-a>    :echo "ctrl-shift-a received"<CR>
map <C-a>      :echo "ctrl-a received"<CR>
```

But all I ever get when pressing either of the two, is the output "ctrl-a received" in the status line. Apparently, vi does not see a difference between a capitalized control character and a lowercase one.

Is there a way to change this?

I am running vi (v7.4) in an xterm (X.Org 6.8.99).

Answer (score 6):

This is a terminal restriction, because vi sees the keycodes as being the same. One can verify this by going into insert mode <kbd>i</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to put vi in a mode to expect the literal input of a special character and then hit e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. A `^A` output will appear. Now do the sequence <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, and again a `^A` will appear: Both input sequences result in the same keycode being seen by vi.

For terminals such as `xterm` you can change that. For `gnome-terminal` [which ignores the X resources settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/401443/28323) I don't know how to do the following:

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1506764/923794) covers the same topic, and [this example](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xterm/XTerm) shows this in use for mapping multiple keys in the `.Xresources` file. E.g.:

```
XTerm*vt100.translations: #override \
  Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>a: string(0x1b) string("[65;5u") \n\
  Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>b: string(0x1b) string("[66;5u") \n\ 
  Ctrl ~Meta Shift <Key>f: string(0x1b) string("[70;5u")
```

Now we have different key sequences coming into vi for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

We can now map them differently in `~/.vimrc`:

```
map <ESC>[65;5u   :echo "ctrl-shift-a received"<CR>
map <C-a>         :echo "ctrl-a received"<CR>
```